# Is there a way to run scripts without having to re-authorize them everytime I copy the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, authorization

I have a spreadsheet that has about 4-5 scripts running.

I am trying to create a library of programs using this spreadsheet.  So I am copy and pasting the spreadsheet.

Each time I use a new copied spreadsheet I have to re-authorize/run the scripts.

Is there any way to prevent the need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there isn't. each new spreadsheet has its own unique ID and authorization is granted per that ID - that's why you are prompted with re-authorizations

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Very frustrating though.